# Passing parameter to telerik popup

Tags: asp.net, telerik, popup

Is there any way to pass parameter to telerik similar to `window.showModalDialog`

The way we call the `window.showModalDialog`:

```
window.showModalDialog(pageName, MyArgs, 'status:no;dialogHide=true;help:no')
```

`MyArgs` is the parameter we are passing to the popup

Comment: Do you means `RadWindow popup` ? Can you show me your code ?

Answer (score 2):

Try likes this ,

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function openRadWin(MyArgs) {
        radopen("yourPageName.aspx?Parameter=" + MyArgs , "RadWindow1");
    }
</script>
<telerik:RadWindowManager ID="RadWindowManager1" runat="server" EnableShadow="true"
    VisibleStatusbar="false">
    <Windows>
        <telerik:RadWindow ID="RadWindow1" runat="server" ShowContentDuringLoad="false" Width="400px"
            Height="400px" Title="Telerik RadWindow" Behaviors="Default">
        </telerik:RadWindow>
    </Windows>
</telerik:RadWindowManager>
```

And , at the `Page_Load` of `yourPageName.aspx` , get your passed parameter value using `Request.QueryString["Parameter"]`  .

Comment: hi zey thanks for the answer In your example you are sending the parameter through url. i am just wondering if there is any other way similar to model popup

Comment: `radopen`'s default parameter is ("PageURL","RadWindowName") , I think if you want to add additional parameter , you have to modify  `radopen` or use some Custom Popup Models ! AND thanks for your respond :)

Answer (score 1):

This help article from Telerik shows a way to do it: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/window-programming-using-radwindow-as-dialog.html. It uses a JavaScript object to put the needed data in a custom field in the control's object, which is then accessed by the content page. Of course, you could, alternatively, use a session/cache object on the server.

This demo is also similar: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/controls/examples/integration/gridandwindow/defaultcs.aspx?product=window. Note how parameters are added from the code-behind to the JS function the links execute.

On passing more parameters to radopen() - see this help article: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/window-programming-opening.html. Then you can use the control's client-side API: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/window-programming-radwindow-methods.html.

You can make it modal with the set_modal() method, or through its Modal server property: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/window/examples/modalpopup/defaultcs.aspx.